Is it worth to have only Component teams in Software development?
I am in a Component team setup now where there are only Front-end teams, Business logic teams, SAP teams etc. where they work separately in different Scrum teams, different Sprints, backlogs etc. There is no single feature team that works across the tech stack.
This essentially seems to lead to a Waterfall approach because the only time we can test a feature or a story is when all the teams have completed their work. There is no vertical splitting but only horizontal splitting of the stories - teams essentially do a bunch of tasks rather than real user stories. This also leads to a big Testing effort at the end of the Release because the Individual teams have not tested the User flows because they are focused on only the individual component. This not only takes a lot of time but also results in finding bugs at the end - basically the Waterfall style.
Even if we build some End-End automated tests, they are not stable because the code changes by the component teams keep breaking some or other thing in the full flow. Some are suggesting API testing to solve this but I am not sure if that alone will be sufficient without testing the User flows.
I wonder if this situation is common to component teams and if there is anything that can be done to improve the situation. In particular, I'd like to kow if a feature team with Front-end developers, backend developers, QAs could more easily solve many of the issues because they will deliver a full User story. Any relevant studies or models that can be used to convince the managemnt to move away from this silo based team structures ?

Well, if none of the teams cares about public API they produce, and they keep doing backwards incompatible changes (or rather: are allowed to do that), then indeed, this is pointless. But it sounds like this is the real problem, not the team arrangement. Or in other words: you need a leader with vision and control over the product. That has nothing to do with waterfall or scrum btw.

I don't understand the problem you are trying to solve. You've identified several problems with a component team structure. These are the same problems other teams face with component or feature team structures and why there's a movement to teams that own end-to-end delivery across the whole product.

I understand the movement towards feature teams but what I am being challenged here is that this is how it works with a Service based architecture. If there are feature teams, it will need developers with several different competencies to work across the tech stack and it will not be possible practically. I don't agree to that because the developers here need to know only Java and React but the silos are so strong that they only think in terms of applications/service and a developer working on 1 application is limited to that and doesn't touch the codebase of another application/service.

There is not a movement to feature teams. There is a movement away from feature teams and component teams and towards other types of teams that work across all features and components of a product to deliver value. But I still don't understand the problem. You outline a lot of problems with feature/component teams. What more do you want? I don't understand what problem you are trying to solve.

This question sounds more like a rant, which makes it an attractor for downvotes and close votes. It seems you are after a discussion, but the SE sites are not discussion sites like Reddit. FWIW, a popular architecture today (which includes tech stack as well as organization) are micro services. Those are typically vertical slices of a karger system, and probably the opposite of what you are experiencing now.

I already wrote that I want to hear others' opnion on this topic because this is called a "Software Engineering" site. What other problems can be discussed here ?

@ThomasOwens I was expecting an answer like the one below by Christophe. I already wrote that I want to hear others' opinion on this topic - to get some pointers on how to move forward with this setup and the required arguments to convince the management to change the team organization.

Unfortunately, we don't do opinions here. We expect problems to be about a particular problem. Do you want to treat component teams as a constraint and solve a particular problem in your development process? Do you want to understand how to move away from feature teams to a different organizational structure? These are things that, given more information, we may be able to help with.

@ThomasOwens it appears that the influence of team structure on system architecture is not opinion based but appears to to obey some laws. Not only is there the Conway law, the reverted Conway law, but there is also a lot of findings in the  branch of system thinking, as organisations producing systems are themselves also systems. Unfortunately, relevant questions are often closed here, so that a core element affecting design of software systems remains unknown to a large population of software engineers.

@Christophe I don't disagree with anything you've said. However, I've read the question 4 times now. I don't see a question about a problem that we can help solve. That's not to say that this isn't a topic worth discussing, because it is. We just don't do discussions here. If the question can't be tied back to a specific, solvable problem or resolving some kind of confusion, then it's not a good fit.

@ThomasOwens indeed the last para of the answer calls for opinion based questions, whereas it should have called more objectively for a solution. On the other side these elemznts are already ilplicitly in the question. I've slightly reworded the end to match the SE requirements.

Thanks @Christophe for the edits. Unfortunately, the StackExchange forums have become a gestapo style control forums where a lot of relevant discussions are closed by the moderators whose only aim seems to be a robotic control over the subjective forum rules rather than encouraging different questions. I have listed several problems in the question but the moderators still believe that there are no problems there. How else should a question be asked in a "Software Engineering" forum ? I'm not asking to solva a null pointer exception in a code.

@Marck: when you want your question to be reopened, it is usually not helpful to insult people.

If you have only component teams in your project, you'll get a compartmentalized design, which makes it very difficult to grasp the picture beyond component.
There is a reason for that: Conway's law will cause the architecture of the teams to drive the architecture of the system. Moreover, some thinkers found out that:

If the architecture of the system and the architecture of the organization are at odds, the architecture of the organization wins - Ruth Malan

To get some cross-component alignment requires several component teams to work closely together and for more complex business processes, to even agree on a shared roadmap. This does not require a waterfall approach. Techniques like Scrum of scrums or Scaled Agile are designed to overcome the team boundaries.
Tests and API alone will not break the spirit of component kingdoms. Only humans caring will do.  There are several ways out of this situation:

Read "Team topologies", a masterpiece about teams organization, and reorganise your teams structure to have some teams responsible for an end to end flow.
If big reorgs are not an option, start small and create at least some temporary task forces for new end-to-end features, with key contributors of the teams involved. While teams will still focus on their component delivery, the task forces will help teams to work in concert.
If this is still not an option, you should at least have a lead team for an end-to-end feature, to actively encourage cooperation.


+1. But let me add I think "Conway's law" should be better called "Conway's observation" - saying it is a "law" gives IMHO a wrong impression about it.

@DocBrown same for the so-called Moore's law. One thing is for sure: any people trying to demonstrate organisational kind of "laws" are confronted with the Hawthorne effect messing up their numbers ;-)

Fortunately, this was not called "Hawthorne's law" ;-)
